# Showing all Sibling nodes that share the same Taxonomy term in Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I made a Taxonomy named `Category` which has terms as following:-

- Term 1
- Term 2
- Term 3
- Term 4

As a requirement, any node that I create has to select one term mentioned above.

Now, what I wanna do is; that when I visit any node page, it should show me all the node titles that share the common term.

As an example, if I selected `Term 2` as a category when creating following nodes:-

- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 3
- Node 4
- Node 5
- Node 6

I want the list of all these nodes when I visit any of these nodes.

My URL, when I visit any of these nodes is:-

```
http://www.mysite.com/term_name/node_name
```

Thanks.

### P.S.

I tried `Views arg parent term` within a view and followed instructions here (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arg_parent_term), but it seems it works with a Taxonomy Term ID and I guess my URL has Taxonomy Name in it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add validator when filter value is AVAILABLE or Default is provided:

[image: At the bottom of the screentshot you sent]